# How to add avatar for MUC room?

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd, smack, multiuserchat

I Have created Chat group using MUC with smack libarary.i use ejabbed server.
I have no idea about how to add Avatar for MUC room.
Is there any option to add avtar image for MUC?

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XMPP Multi user chat setting avatar image for the group chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35308977/xmpp-multi-user-chat-setting-avatar-image-for-the-group-chat)

Answer (score 1):

Ejabberd supports MUC Avatar from muc vcard support. You can check official doc [here](https://docs.ejabberd.im/tutorials/muc-vcard/).

Now you said on client side you are using smack library, I don't know if they by default support MUC vcard. Even if they don't support it, you could easily code it up yourself and integrate it with smack as a module.